# "is it me, or..." meaning and usage

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does "is it me, or..." mean?

Examples:

- [Perhaps it is just me, but I find Intel's ultrabook pitch somewhat confusing.](http://www.tomshardware.com/news/intel-ultrabook-computex-taiwan-netbook-notebook-tablet,12846.html#xtor=RSS-181)
- [Is it me, or is this a bug?](http://magazine.joomla.org/issues/Issue-Mar-2011/item/391-Is-it-me-or-is-this-a-bug)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it me = is it my mistake/fault.

"Is it me, or is this a bug?" - Is this my fault for not understanding something or is it a bug.

The implication is normally that you don't really think it is your mistake so it's phrased as a faked apology. ie `I might be mistaken but I don't really believe I am`.

It can also be used to make an insult/comment, "Is it me or should she really not be wearing that at her age?", assumes those you are talking to agree with you.

Comment: @Martin Beckett: It doesn't *have* to be a matter of mistakes / fault / blame. Oftentimes I might say it in a far more literal mode - for example, in contexts where I've noticed something and wonder if others have too.

Comment: @funblefingers - yes "is it just me or is everyone on EL&U a pedant?" Is a slightly different connotation of, I assume you would agree with me

Comment: @Martin Beckett, @FumbleFingers: Thanks for your answer and comments.

Comment: I often hear the phrase 'Is it me or is it cold/hot in here?' which is used when somebody is concerned whether their body temperature is normal, or everbody else is experiencing the same thing.

Comment: @Ambo100 - I would 'translate' this as. I'm hot/cold - does everyone agree with me? Because you should!

Comment: @Martin Beckett, No, it's more than just stating how you feel, in a way it's used to ask subtly whoever you with whether they too are hot/cold.

Comment: @Ambo100  - yes that's what I meant. The point is that you don't really believe it's just you but are trying to find a polite way of expressing your opinion without expressing yourself. It's definitely an English thing!